# How to avoid calling javadoc more than once if creating a site?

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-site-plugin, maven-javadoc-plugin

I would like to deploy an artifact together with javadoc and a Maven site. I use

```
clean javadoc:jar site deploy site:deploy
```

(the split between `site` and `site:deploy` is just to avoid the deployment of a site if `deploy` fails).

Now the javadoc is created twice - once in `javadoc:jar` and once in `site`. Is it possible to create it just once and use it both for the `javadoc-jar` in Nexus and the Maven site?

Comment: Did you try to add  <reporting> section to your pom, to generate javadocs as part of the site generation?

Comment: javadoc _is_ generated in the site build, but is not bundled into a jar (unless I also call javadoc:jar)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the plugin is missing a check if the output is already generated as part of the Maven session. Would be a nice improvement to verify if the output is generated *after* Maven had started. (and let's add a force-parameter to enforce the creation anyway).

Comment: I'm sorry, actually I don't understand your advice (or what I should try)? As we start with a `clean`, everything is created after Maven has started.

Comment: It is not an advice, I'm saying that if you call 2 goals of the maven-javadoc-plugin, it will call the javadoc tool twice due to missing optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution that may you use is creation two different scripts for build/deploy and run them one by one:

1. Firstly - full build with with -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true, that avoids you to create javadoc
2. Another - only run mvn javadoc:javadoc command to get actual javadoc

Also, maybe next link help you:

1. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/selective-javadocs-report.html
2. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/test-javadocs.html

So, you can specify execution phase of javadoc plugin and specify reportSet.